# Obtaining Consistent Estimators Based on Uniform Distribution

Tags: estimation, parameter-estimation

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be a random sample distributed according to the uniform distribution $\mathcal{U}(\theta,\theta+1)$.

Let $U$ be the largest sample, and $V$ be the smallest sample.

Then, which of the following will be consistent estimator of $\theta$:

1. $U$
2. $V$
3. $2U-V-2$
4. $2V-U+1$

I have studied that for a distribution with some parameter taking values in $[a,b]$, then the Maximum of the samples will be consistent for $b$ and minimum of Samples will be conistent $a$. So, following this Theorem first and second options seems true.

Also, function of consistent estimators are also Consistent. Hence, the third and fourth options are also Consistent. So, I conclude that all the options given here will be consistent. I don't know whether I have used correct rationale behind this. Please tell me if I am doing anything incorrect here. Thanks

Comment: The main thing you are missing: if $X$ is consistent for a parameter $a$ then $f(X)$ is consistent for $f(a)$, not for $a$. That said, in this context all you need to do is compute $\lim_{n \to \infty} E[U]$ and the same for $V$ (since all your options are just affine functions of $U$ and $V$).

Comment: So, does it mean not all of the options are consistent?

Comment: Indeed they are not all consistent for $\theta$. This distinction of being consistent for a parameter in particular (as opposed to any parameter whatsoever) may be what is actually confusing you.

Comment: @lan Doesn't this invariance property depends on the estimator? For example, the method of moments estimator is consistent but doesn't have the invariance property! Plus convergence of moments isn't the same as being consistent in general. You need to use the correct definition: convergence in probability.

Comment: @user144410 You're correct of course, but in practice these are the heuristics: when $X_n$ converges in probability to a constant $a$ and $f$ is continuous at that constant, $f(X_n)$ converges in probability to $f(a)$. And when $X_n$ converges in probability to some constant, that is almost always going to be $\lim_{n \to \infty} E[X_n]$; non-uniformly integrable cases are atypical in practice.

Answer (score 1):

$U$ is consistent for $\theta + 1$ (the maximum of the samples) ; therefore $U$ is *not* consistent for $\theta$ but $U-1$ is.

$V$ is consistent for $\theta$ (the minimum of the samples)

$2U-V-2$ converges in probability to $2\theta+2-\theta-2 = \theta$ so it is consistent for $\theta$

$2V- U +1$ converges in probability to $2\theta-\theta-1+1 = \theta$ so it is consistent for $\theta$

(where the [continuous-mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem) theorem was used for the last two conclusions)